# Centering images horizontally in container div when height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, image

Sorry if this has been answered - I've tried virtually all the tips I've already come across so far on centering images without any luck. This image just refuses to center horizontally!

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HkuMW/4/)

**HTML:** *(Note: images are note mine, just taken from google as examples)*

Each image either receives "height:100%;" or "width:100%;" when loading depending on whether the height to width ratio is within or outside of the 4:3 ratio in landscape orientation.

This is done to ensure the image completely fills the containing div no matter what size and shape it is.

```
<div class="imgOuter">
    <div class="imgInner">
        <img src="http://www.woroni.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Cars-Lamborghini-Free-Wallpaper.jpg" style="height: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="imgOuter">
    <div class="imgInner">
        <img src="http://cdn.acidcow.com/pics/20100118/celebrity_portraits_by_tom_munro_03.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

The main outer div is set to conform to the constant aspect ratio of 4:3
The inner div adds a border internally to the outer div which must remain specifically sized.

```
div.imgOuter{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.3333%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:none;
}
div.imgInner{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #444;
    cursor:pointer;
}
div.imgInner>img{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

.imgInner: I have tried text-align:center; tried additionally dimensioning with height and width @ 100%...

You'll notice in the fiddle that the second image is in a portrait orientation and sits perfectly as expected centered vertically.

If you take a landscape image and set the width to 100% instead of height, it also centers vertically without issue, leaving white space above and below its ratio is wider than 4:3.

Only when the height is 100% does the image default to left alignment seemingly ignoring the left and right positioning.

My only suspicion is that the div.imgOuter does not have a height, only a padding value. If thats the case then I'm stuck attempting to solve both scaling aspect ratios and center alignment :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly sure you can't do this with CSS alone--because any negative margin workarounds for horizontal and vertical centering only works when you can used fixed sizes (as using a negative percentage margin will take the percentage from the parent container rather than the element's original size.)

However, you can do this with JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/HkuMW/7/

So, we apply the percentage `left` and `top` to sit exactly in the middle (but from the image's top-left corner):

```
div.imgInner>img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

Then we use jQuery to re-position the image by finding out the exact pixel dimensions, halving it, and popping that in:

```
$('.imgInner > img').each(function (i) {
    var imgWidth = ((0 - parseInt($(this).css('width'))) / 2);
    var imgHeight = ((0 - parseInt($(this).css('height'))) / 2);

    $(this).css('margin-top', imgHeight);
    $(this).css('margin-left', imgWidth);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess you would just need to re-call this function when the browser was re-sized.

Comment: I took this idea solved it server side during the loading script rather than in browser.
If the image height/width >=0.75 then the width is just set to 100% and we're happy.
If the height/width<0.75 then the left position is set as a percentage value: ((((ImgH-(ImgW*75%))/ImgH)/2)*100)

This basically compares the aspect ration to 4:3 and equates what the loaded image is off by with respect to the width.

The image will now scale without shifting along with the constant ratio container.

Comment: updated fiddle for anyone trying to solve this in the future: http://jsfiddle.net/HkuMW/18/

Answer (score 0):

See if this answers your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/HkuMW/17/

You can change the `background-size:100% auto;` to `background-size:auto 100%;` if you need to swap the resizing method.

Comment: thanks Manoj, with the CSS inserted inline server side this is a solution as well. Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HkuMW/19/

Either way the solution requires shifting rules based on image assessment logic. We'll work out if its more efficient server side, or client side later on.